# Footnote URL linking entire page

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, urls

I'm using `\footcite{example}` citations in my paper. When the citations produces a URL that starts on one PDF page and then finishes in the following page, it highlights all words on the in-between page in the body of the text with the URL. So, clicking on any word in the page links to the URL site. How do I prevent this from happening?

I'm rendering the PDF in Texpad.